# Finding the UMVUE of the variance of a gaussian with mean zero

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, estimation, variance, mathematical-statistics

Given $Z_1, ..., Z_n, \sim\mathcal{N}(0, θ^2), θ>0$. Define $X_i=|Z_i|$ and consider estimation of $\theta$ and  $θ^2$ on the basis of the random sample $X_1,...X_n$. Find the uniformly minimum variance unbiased estimator (UMVUE) of $θ^2$.

Comment: Since the mean of the $Z_i$ is known to be $0$, what is the UMVUE of $\theta^2$ if you were given the $Z_i$'s instead of the $X_i$'s? What would happen if each occurrence of $Z_i^2$ in this UMVUE is replaced by $|Z_i|^2 = X_i^2$?